# Cannot redirect to a path in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

In laravel 5.1 I have overwrite postRegister then redirect it to a path and it worked well, but in Laravel 5.2 I write the same code it didn't work. here some of my code

```
public function postRegister(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = $this->validator($request->all());

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            $this->throwValidationException(
                $request, $validator
            );
        }

        $this->create($request->all());

        return redirect('login');
    }
```

this I want to redirect to page login after user register.

I got the problem like this:

> ErrorException in SessionGuard.php line 411: Argument 1 passed to
>   Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::login() must implement interface
>   Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, null given

**Note:** I used laravel default scafold

Thanks in advance

Comment: where is the call to Auth::login happening ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`postRegister()` is no longer the method to override. Use this instead:

```
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $validator = $this->validator($request->all());

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $this->throwValidationException(
            $request, $validator
        );
    }

    Auth::guard($this->getGuard())->login($this->create($request->all()));

    return redirect(route('route.after.register'));
}
```

Don't forget to import the Auth Facade:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your routes inside the `web` middleware ? Laravel 5.2 has a new feature called middleware groups. In order to use session, your route should be inside the `web` middleware. If you check your `Kernel.php`, you will get a clear idea about the middlewares inside the `web` middleware group

```
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
    ],
```

Comment: @ nauphal here is my route  Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
    Route::auth();
    Route::get('account/verify/{activation_code}', 'Auth\AuthController@verify');

    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
});